# Match date pattern from log file, compare it to current date and print the corresponding line

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I would like to create `bash` script that compares the **date** of each line in a **log file** to the **current date** and if the difference is more than **1 day** then it prints the corresponding line to another file.

Can you support?

Below is a sample log file:

```
2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0165_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0165_abcd_44159@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_10197@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_11339@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;2016-11-01 07:10:51 GST;faultManager:network@ER_AO_L_4283_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ER_AO_L_4283_abcd_14179@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
2016-11-01 11:26:58 GST;2016-11-01 11:26:58 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0166_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0166_abcd_14126@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
2016-11-03 10:00:08 GST;2016-11-03 10:00:08 GST;faultManager:network@ET_AO_L_0193_abcd@eNBEquip@eNBInst@x2Grp-0@x2Access-0_424_02_ET_AO_L_0193_abcd_16113@x2Transp-0|alarm-2632-3-698;
```

Here is what i have implemented so far:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < /cygdrive/f/Script_X2/Final/Test/ActiveX2Alarms2.log

for i in "${lines[@]}"
do
echo $i > /cygdrive/f/Script_X2/Final/Test/abcd.log
toDate=`awk -F";" '{print $1}' /cygdrive/f/Script_X2/Final/Test/abcd.log`
echo $toDate

toDate2=`date -d"${toDate}" +'%Y-%m-%d'`
echo "toDate2: $toDate2"

currentDate=`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`
echo "currentDate: $currentDate"

diff=`$currentDate - $toDate`
echo $diff

if [ `$currentDate - $toDate2` -gt 1 ]; 
then
    awk -F";" '{print $4}' /cygdrive/f/Script_X2/Final/Test/abcd.log >> SiteIDs_extracted.log
fi

done
```

Comment: There are two dates given in the log file. `2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;2016-09-29 23:40:14 GST;` Which date would need to compared with the current date or both are the same?

Comment: edited the question and added the code i have done so far, both dates are the same so let's consider the first one.

Comment: The problem is what you think some commands do, like `diff=\`$currentDate - $toDate\``. This one should report an error message at least. Do yu think this command gets the difference in days from two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk -v d="$(date -d "yesterday" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" '$1 " " $2 < d' file
```

It sets yesterday's timestamp to `d` and outputs records that have timestamps prior it.